# How to add tabs at bottom of the flexslider

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to use control tabs at bottom of the flexslider. Here I don't know how to enable the tabs.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="button_slide">
 <div class="button_slides" style="border-left:2px solid #CFD6E4">
   introduction
 </div>
 <div class="button_slides">
   Specialist consultants
 </div>
 <div class="button_slides">
   Bespoke solutions
 </div>
 <div class="button_slides">
   Conference and events
 </div>
 <div class="button_slides manage">
   Manamgement information system
 </div>
 <div class="button_slides" style="border-right:2px solid #CFD6E4">
   introduction
 </div>
```

Here is my script:

```
  $(window).load(function() {
     $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide"
     });
  });
```

[Here I have attached the screen shot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9wsO.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript**

```
// Can also be used with $(document).ready()
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: "thumbnails"      <--------- This
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- Place somewhere in the <body> of your page -->
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li data-thumb="1">
      Content here.
    </li>
    <li data-thumb="2">
      Content here.
    </li>
    <li data-thumb="3">
      Content here.
    </li>
    <li data-thumb="4">
      Content here.
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

#### Edit:

**The plugin doesn't work this way. Try to change hard code values into the actual `js` file, as that appears to be creating the image:**

`jQuery.flexslider.js`

Change the `slider.pagingCount` function on `line 212` to:

```
      if (slider.pagingCount > 1) {
        for (var i = 0; i < slider.pagingCount; i++) {
          slide = slider.slides.eq(i);

          slider.controlNavScaffold.append('<li></li>');
          j++;
        }
      }
```

It probably has to do with this appended element `li` from the `var item` that contains an `img` tag:

```
      if (slider.pagingCount > 1) {
        for (var i = 0; i < slider.pagingCount; i++) {
          slide = slider.slides.eq(i);
          item = (slider.vars.controlNav === "thumbnails") ? '<img src="' + slide.attr( 'data-thumb' ) + '"/>' : '<a>' + j + '</a>';
          if ( 'thumbnails' === slider.vars.controlNav && true === slider.vars.thumbCaptions ) {
            var captn = slide.attr( 'data-thumbcaption' );
            if ( '' != captn && undefined != captn ) item += '<span class="' + namespace + 'caption">' + captn + '</span>';
          }
          slider.controlNavScaffold.append('<li>' + item + '</li>');
          j++;
        }
      }
```

Comment: When I use this thumbnails it display like as image. so couldn't add tab content. Refer my attachment. I would like to display like that. when I click that tabs the slide should be navigate depends upon the headings

Comment: I have changed the code. The iamges only disappered. But the content tab still not working :( I have put the html code for tabs out of on <ul class="slides">. I don't have any idea how to enable the tabs :(

Comment: Yeah, I'm shooting in the dark here. I don't have the plugin. I'm sure it's something with this (answer updated)